# Is it possible to determine by reflection if method parameter is final?

Tags: java, reflection, parameters, final, modifiers

Is it possible to find out, if the parameter of method is `final`?
I have tried this:

```
int modifiers = method.getParameters()[0].getModifiers() // modifiers == 0
```

But even if first parameter has `final` modifier, `modifiers` is set to zero.

edit: I really don't think that my question is a duplicate. When I try this code with members of class (such as fields, methods, etc.), it works perfectly. But with method parameters `getModifiers` fails!

edit2: In questions you suggested me as similar I didn't find an answer... So could you help me, how to check if parameter is final?

Comment: Just curious: why do you care?

Comment: @Ivonet I though that also but nope. This is about method parameters. title is a bit misleading.

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44695589/6413377) is closely related. Using the suggested dupes method returns 0 when it should return 16 for `final` which leads `isFinal()=false`.

Comment: Actually the question is quite close to be a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44672092/6413377) even that is from annotation point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a brief study I am afraid that it is not possible. See first comment on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44672092/6413377)

> If you looked at a decompiled class, you could see that the compiler
>   erases the final keyword from all final parameters. And it is
>   reasonable because the final makes sense only at compile time.

I tried to find more proof on this but failed on that. Anyway I made a small test based on the 1st suggested dubes answer.

Having test class like

```
public class TestClass {
   public void testMethod(final Integer param) {} // could be also int
}
```

and running this test/logging

```
@Test
public void testIsFinal() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
   Method method = TestClass.class.getMethod("testMethod", Integer.class);
   log.info("method {}", method);
   Parameter[] params = method.getParameters();
   log.info("params {}", params);
   log.info("params[0] {}", params[0]);
   log.info("modifiers {}", params[0].getModifiers());
   log.info("final {}", Modifier.isFinal( params[0].getModifiers() ));
}
```

logs

> 2017-12-11 13:11:24.512 INFO  org.example.jpa.JUnitTest:33  - method public void org.example.jpa.JUnitTest$TestClass.testMethod(java.lang.Integer)
>   2017-12-11 13:11:24.521 INFO  org.example.jpa.JUnitTest:36  - params[0] java.lang.Integer arg0
>   2017-12-11 13:11:24.521 INFO  org.example.jpa.JUnitTest:37  - modifiers 0
>   2017-12-11 13:11:24.522 INFO  org.example.jpa.JUnitTest:38  - final false

so it seems that the only allowed method parameter modifier `final` does not exist in compiled method declaration. Note that it neither exists in logged methods signature

```
public void org.example.jpa.JUnitTest$TestClass.testMethod(java.lang.Integer)
```

From [source code  of `Modifier`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.java)

```
public static final int FINAL            = 0x00000010;
```

and

```
/**
  * The Java source modifiers that can be applied to a method or constructor parameter.
  * @jls 8.4.1 Formal Parameters
  */
 private static final int PARAMETER_MODIFIERS = Modifier.FINAL;
```

and

```
public static boolean isFinal(int mod) {
   return (mod & FINAL) != 0;
}
```

so to tell that method parameter was declared as `final` the second bit should be 1.